# React native with expo fonts working on expo snack but not on visual studio code

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fonts, expo

I am doing my fonts the right way but I keep getting this error

**You started loading the font "Alef-Bold", but used it before it finished loading. You need to wait for Font.loadAsync to complete before
using the font.**

My code works on my expo snack but it does not on my vscode. What could be the problem? and this is the [link](https://snack.expo.io/@vuyi/font-loading) to my snack.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to `await` the `useFonts` call like this

```
const LoadFonts = async () => {
  await useFonts(); // We have to await this call here..
};
```

[Working Example Here](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/font-loading)

Comment: Thank  you very much. This did the trick it worked.